# JSONSerialization and EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsjsonserialization

I fetch some information from a MYSQL database with the help of a php service. At the end i push it through `echo json_encode($resultArray)` to my app. Now I have a problem with JSONSerialization and here is my code.

```
If ( urlData != nil ) {
        let res = response as NSHTTPURLResponse!;

        NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);

        if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)
        {
            var responseData:NSString  = NSString(data:urlData!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

            NSLog("Response ==> %@", responseData);

            var error: NSError?

            let jsonData2:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as NSDictionary

            let success:NSInteger = jsonData2.valueForKey("IdUser") as NSInteger
            ...
```

With this code i get an error message `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in the line of `NSJSONSerialization`. Does anybody know why?

The responseDate have this example value:

```
[{"IdUser":"2","preName":"Max","lastName":"Muster"}]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i found the solution. The serialization don't work when the response data has some brackets. Is this normal or is there a way to handle that in xcode?

Comment: Show us the response data.  And tell us what `error` NSJSONSerialization is returning.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON response is not a `NSDictionary`. It is an array. Now this array has one item, which is, itself, a dictionary. But you have to parse the array first:

```
let array = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:nil, error: &error) as NSArray
```

If you want to get the dictionary, you grab the first item from the array:

```
let dictionary = array[0] as NSDictionary
```

And if you want the field value from `IdUser`, you grab that string value and then call `integerValue`:

```
let idUser = dictionary["IdUser"]?.integerValue
```

---

By the way, if it's at all possible that the response may deviate in its format, you may want to be careful with your parsing of the response, employing optional binding to gracefully handle the absence of the data in the format you expected, e.g.:

```
var error: NSError?
if let array = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(urlData!, options:nil, error: &error) as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
    if let dictionary = array.first {
        if let idUser = dictionary["IdUser"]?.integerValue {
            // `IdUser` definitely found; now check the value here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

an easy way to parse json in swift use [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) but if you do not want it, you can do so

```
if let jsonData2 = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: nil)  as? AnyObject {

        }
```

but I strongly recommend to use [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

Comment: Unless you want to attempt to sort SwiftyJSON objects - you need to convert back to NSArray/NSDictionionary. It's very slow... I've actually stopped using SwiftyJSON because of it. The native objects are much faster. If you need to sort, don't use Swifty JSON!